# Integrable - martingale

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $X_{n}^{(1)}$ and $X_{n}^{(2)}$ are martingales w.r.t. a filtration $F_{n}$. I have do determine whether $Z_{n}=e^{X_{n}^{1}+X_{n}^{2}}$ is a martingale, submartingale or supermartingale. I thought that because $X_{n}^{1}+X_{n}^{2}$ is a martingale I can use Jensen to say that $E[Z_{n}|F_{n-1}]\geq e^{E(X_{n}^{(1)}+X_{n}^{(2)}|F_{n-1})}=Z_{n-1}$. But I have to check whether $Z_{n}$ is integrable and I don't know how.

Comment: There is no guarantee that Z is integrable.

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Find some $F_0$-measurable integrable $U$ such that $e^U$ is not integrable and use $X^{(1)}_n=U$, $X^{(2)}_n=0$ for every $n$.

Comment: So there's nothing to prove for the martingale-property because $Z_{n}$ isn't integrable?